# Puppet Parse Order Explanation

Tags: puppet

I am building an auditd audit.rules file based on the the package-provided 30-stig.rules file.

The stig.rules file is located at /usr/share/doc/audit-<version>/rules/30-stig.rules. However, it's hard to know beforehand what version of auditd is installed therefore I wanted to use an exec resource to copy this file to a standard location:

```
exec { 'Copy stig.rules to /tmp/stig.rules':
  command  => 'cp $(rpm -qf auditd | grep stig.rules) /tmp/stig.rules',
  unless   => 'cmp /tmp/stig.rules $(rpm -qf auditd | grep stig.rules)',
}

file { '/etc/audit/audit.rules':
  ensure  => file,
  content => template('auditd/audit.rules.erb'),
}
```

The template (audit.rules.erb) contains:

```
scope.function_file(['/tmp/stig.rules'])
```

I initially got an error that the template could not locate /tmp/stig.rules. Therefore, I added:

```
Exec['Copy stig.rules to /tmp/stig.rules'] -> File['/etc/audit/audit.rules']
```

Even after this explicit ordering I get the same error that /tmp/stig.rules is not found. It seems that during parsing the file resource is doing some pre-validation even before it executes the 'exec' that it should be ordered after. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Your Puppet resources do not match your expected behavior and do not seem to be related to your error. I would not expect the relationship ordering you specified to fix this problem and it does not appear to have done so.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you explain why you feel my resources don't "match my expected behavior"?

Comment: That file is referenced by the template which is referenced by the file resource. That's why it's strange to me that it would parse the template before the file resource should even have been run (since the exec hadn't yet run).

Comment: Oh I glossed over that part. Ok, so this still has nothing to with resource order, but rather this nuance that tends to trip up a lot of Puppet newcomers: "Functions execute on the Puppet master. They do not execute on the Puppet agent. Hence they only have access to the commands and data available on the Puppet master host." https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html

Comment: That makes more sense. So, in this case, wanting to use the most up-to-date 'stig.rules' file relevant to the version of the audit package deployed on the client (which may not match the version deployed to the Puppet master) is just not possible?

Comment: You can do this in a different way, such as deploying the file yourself.

Comment: Of course. But this one files, stig.rules, is only a _piece_ of the final audit.rules file which is why I'm using a template to build up the final file in pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem you are having is that Puppet functions execute on the Puppet Master.

Typically, this problem would be solved by creating a [custom fact](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/3.6/custom_facts.html) that returns the auditd version.

Create a file in your module with something like:

```
# lib/facter/auditd_version.rb

Facter.add(:auditd_version) do
  confine :osfamily => 'RedHat'
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.exec('rpm -q --queryformat "%{VERSION}\n" audit')
  end
end
```

You can then reference your file path in the manifest using:

```
$file_path = "/usr/share/doc/audit-${facts['auditd_version']}/rules/30-stig.rules"
```

or (legacy):

```
$file_path = "/usr/share/doc/audit-${::auditd_version}/rules/30-stig.rules"
```

And you can access it in an ERB template using:

```
/usr/share/doc/audit-<%= @auditd_version %>/rules/30-stig.rules
```

If you then need the content of the stig rules file inside your manifest, you would typically transfer that content into your Puppet manifest, and allow Puppet to manage that file:

```
$stig_rules = template('mymodule/stig_rules.erb')
file { "/usr/share/doc/audit-${facts['auditd_version']}/rules/30-stig.rules":
  ensure  => file,
  content => $stig_rules,
}
```

And then inside your template you can now access that content as `@stig_rules`.

In the event that the RPM occasionally changes the content of that file, you would then need to update your Puppet manifest - true, that is not ideal.

Another approach would be to simply return the entire file contents in a custom fact.

```
# lib/facter/stig_rules.rb

Facter.add(:stig_rules) do
  confine :osfamily => 'RedHat'
  setcode do
    Facter::Core::Execution.exec("cat \
      /usr/share/doc/audit-#{Facter.value(:auditd_version)}/stig.rules")
  end
end
```

Comment: I actually did this very thing. I created the custom fact which gives the client-side auditd version. However, when I'm trying to insert the content of it into the template I still have to use the 'file' function in the ERB which, as you said, still executes on the server-side.

Comment: Doing a custom fact with the entire content would likely work. I previously created a custom fact pointing to the stig.rules file. However, that information is on the client-side and, as you pointed out, the ERB function would attempt to locate the same file on the server-side so that wouldn't work for all distros or if the auditd version differed between client and server.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding. I believe most people in this situation would allow Puppet to manage the stig.rules file, by copying whatever the RPM provides into the Puppet module, and then declaring that file resource and its content. Puppet sees that the file that is already there (delivered by the RPM) has the expected content, and so does nothing. If you have different files for different OSes, then you do conditional logic based on e.g. `$facts['osfamily']`. All said though, I think getting a custom fact to simply return the entire content of the file should also be fine.